# batch file find string and give line number off it

Tags: batch-file

i m trying to compile batch file to search a string on a txt file and when it finds give the line number and place it to a variable so i can use it on a statement

### example

```
name.txt

carolina
rita
sara
andre
```

---

in the example above i whant to find %username% = Andre and then return to a variable the number 4 if the %username% is not on the list i whant it to atribut the name "Hello"
because the "andre" is in line 4

i found a code but icant adatp it to function

```
    @echo off &setlocal
set "search=%username%"
set "replace=kordo anstataui"
set "textfile=name.txt"
set "newfile=new.txt"

(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "%textfile%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"

type "%newfile%"
```

i hope it help the code helps

Ps:sorry for my bad writing

Answer (score 4):

You found the FINDSTR command. Hmmm, I wonder what it might do...

```
for /f "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /i /x /n andre "%textfile%"') do set line=%%N
```

Use `help findstr` or `findstr /?` from a command prompt to get help. Refer to [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053) for additional info not available in the standard help.

Comment: hello after a lot o seaching i found what i whant but i cant put it to work i found another code for my problem and it works i tried to change the "Installer ID:" for a variable but it wont work i need to search %username% instead of "installer id:"if i can do that my problem is solved @echo off
set "file=build_info.txt"
set "installer_id="
for /f "tokens=2* delims=: " %%A in (
  'findstr /bc:"Installer ID:" "%file%"'
) do set "installer_id=%%B" echo %installer_id%
pause>null

Comment: @user3121120 then replace "Installer ID:" with "%username%". This will now search for the username and store that in the INstaller ID variable

Comment: @dbenham: When I `echo !line!` from `for /f "delims=:" %N in ('findstr /i /x /n andre "%textfile%"') do set line=%N` I get a response `!line!` instead of the number 4. Do you know why?

Comment: @Zimba - Probably because delayed expansion has not enabled. - `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`

Comment: @dbenham: it is enabled. Here's what I had: 
`for /f "delims=:" %N in ('findstr /i /x /n andre "name.txt"') do set line=%N
echo %line%
%line%
echo !line!
!line!` It's working now, after I pasted the code from my comment. Didn't work at first when  I edited it in Notepad to remove the extra %, and still doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This code gives all lines containing `andre` and stores the last line containing the match in a variable:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=][" %i in ('find /n "andre" ^< name.txt') do echo Hello %j, you are in line %i & set line=%i
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this one as is very simple.

```
FOR /F "delims=: tokens=1*" %i in ('findstr /N /I "String2Find" "file2read.log"') do ( set VARIABLE=%i )
echo %VARIABLE%
```

Comment: But this doesn't solve the question, how to store the line number in a variable

Comment: sorry, this will return it as a variable. if you have multiple hits. You will get the last one.

Comment: But now it's a duplicate of the answer from dbenham

Comment: i would call it a variation of that one but yes, it should be a comment on that one and not answer.